# How to inject a service into a constructor when creating a new instance of an object?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

**The Setup:** I've registered a configuration service that pulls data from appsettings.json and it works fine. I also have a controller that uses that service to get settings from that file, again this works like it's supposed to:

```cs
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    private readonly string _apiUri;
    public ApiController(IOptions<Configurator> config)
    {
        _apiUri = config.Value.ApiSettings.ApiBaseUrl + 
                  config.Value.ApiSettings.ApiVersion;
    }
    //...
}
```

Now note, I'm new to automated unit testing and to asp.net core. What I'd like to do is to decouple the ApiController's reliance on the injected service so that I can use a separate XUnit test project to test functions inside the controller, similar to the example in [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-core/1414/unit-testing-aspnet-core).

To do this I created a model and interface representing the ApiSettings section of my appsettings.json file:

```cs
"ApiSettings": {
    "ApiBaseUrl": "https://example.com/api/",
    "ApiVersion": "v1/"
}
```

The Model:

```cs
public class ApiSettings : IApiSettings
{
    public string ApiBaseUri { get; set; }
    public string ApiVersion { get; set; }
}
```

The Interface:

```cs
public interface IApiSettings
{
    string ApiBaseUri { get; set; }
    string ApiVersion { get; set; }
}
```

I then created a class that would be dependent on the service to inject the settings:

```cs
public class ApiSettingsBuilder
{
    private readonly string _apiUri;
    public ApiSettingsBuilder(IOptions<Configurator> config)
    {
        _apiUri = config.Value.ApiSettings.ApiBaseUrl + 
                  config.Value.ApiSettings.ApiVersion;
    }

    public string ApiUri { get { return _apiUri; } }
}
```

**The Problem:** How do I create an new instance of this class?

```cs
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    private readonly string _apiUri;
    public ApiController()
    {
        ApiSettingsBuilder builder = new ApiSettingsBuilder(/*What do I do here*/);
        _apiUri = builder.ApiUri;
    }

    public ApiController(IApiSettings settings)
    {
        //For testing
        _apiUri = settings.ApiBaseUrl + settings.ApiVersion;
    }
    //...
}
```

Also, I know this is all a bit overkill, but I would still like an answer because It would possibly be useful in other scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to create new classes for unit testing purposes, you can mock the interface of your IOptions using appropriate framework, e.g. Moq:

```
var configurator = new Configurator() { ApiBaseUrl = "abc" };
var mock = new Mock<IOptions<Configurator>>();
mock.Setup(ap => ap.Value).Returns(configurator);
```

Then you can pass mocked object to your constructor for unit testing:

```
var controller = new ApiController(mock.Object);
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure how to go about mocking a service. I guess my thought of "decoupling" my controller was also unnecessary because that's what injecting a service does - I just wasn't thinking about what was actually happening.

Comment: Small tip, you can use Options.Create(...) to make an IOptions<T> from a T